# not find the inner text of Div in elemntRef in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I write this code to find innerText of div and change it but when I click on the button to find innerText it shows me `undefined`.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxeblp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<p #dviInner>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<button (click)="clickinDiv()">click</button>
```

and ts code :

```
@ViewChild('dviInner',{static:false}) dviInner:ElementRef;
 clickinDiv():void{
    console.log(this.dviInner.nativeElement.innerHtml)
  }
```

**what's the problem ? how can o solve this problem ????**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be "innerHTML" not "innerHtml"
HTML must be in all caps

```
clickinDiv():void{
    console.log(this.dviInner.nativeElement.innerHTML)
  }
```

I have updated the code in stackBlitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-innerporj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: in the main project i write all this code but still it show me this error `Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined`

Comment: do it step by step, for ex:- console.log(this.dviInner) , the again log,console.log(this.dviInner.nativeElement) and then console.log(this.dviInner.nativeElement.innerHTML). You will understand the properties by logging it

Comment: @mrcoder was it helpful or you are still finding it difficult ?